# Error in VarSelLCM: At least one variable is neither numeric, integer nor factor

Tags: r, variables, cluster-analysis

When i try to run VarSelLCM R package for latent class analysis, i get the following error:

"Error in VSLCMdataMixte(x) : 
  At least one variable is neither numeric, integer nor factor!
In addition: There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)"

Here is the code i run on RStudio:

```
> res_with <- VarSelCluster(x, 2, nbcores = 2, initModel=40)
```

And here the output of the code < warnings():

```
> warnings()
```

Warning messages:
1: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
6: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
7: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
8: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
9: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
10: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
11: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
12: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
13: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
14: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
15: In type[j] <- class(x[, j]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to find the bug without your data. What is the output of:

```
summary(x)
```

I think that at least one of your variable does not have the right type. For instance character are not allowed.

Concerning the warnings, they inform you that some levels have a frequency of 0...